# What is the advantage in using sub-domains in network naming conventions?

Tags: design

Although our devices are named things like:

```
atln-0102-rt06-ge0
```

I often see naming conventions that use sub-domains like this:

```
cr06-0102-ge0.atln.example.net
```

Or even:

```
ge0.cr06-0102.atln.example.net
```

When would I want to incorporate sub-domains into the naming convention and what are the advantages?

Comment: Subdomains are branches in a tree. They can be delegated. Individual records can't.

Comment: @RickyBeam - Is that advantageous in a network device naming convention?

Comment: It's somewhere personal choice. we have small network with flat naming, if you have ginormous network then you need sub-domain base on location geo location etc which is easy to translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in style of naming often depends on how the network is provisioned and managed.  If all assets are inventoried in a single central database, the first might be better, especially if it already generates those unique IDs.  On the other hand, if the provisioning and configuration is done locally at individual sites (e.g. the "atln" in your example), then being able to delegate a subdomain such that they don't need to interact with a central repository to deploy might be desired, and so the second form is preferred.

That having been said...  In actual practice usually neither of these is a sufficient factor to turn the tide and it's just a matter of taste for the initial deployment team.  Personally, I like using the tree structure of the DNS to represent structure in the network, but I've known other Network Engineers that strongly favor the flat style of naming.